# Can I share named pipe between app and framework

Tags: android, linux

Here is an image of the structure of Android.
[Android STRUCTURE http://p.blog.csdn.net/images/p_blog_csdn_net/yuanyou/EntryImages/20090517/android-system-architecture1.jpg](http://p.blog.csdn.net/images/p_blog_csdn_net/yuanyou/EntryImages/20090517/android-system-architecture1.jpg)

My question is: Can I share named pipe between apps and app framework? As I know, libc is available for apps using NDK.

For example, I create a named pipe in an app, since the knowledge of filesystem between apps and app framework is the same, can I use the named pipe to share something between them?

I want to achieve a firewall on Android. But the application layer doesn't provide the API I need, so I try to figure out whether I should modify the app framework or not. I want to let the send method which sends the packet to the destination stop a few seconds and talk to an app in the top layer to negotiate sth.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?